# WPF Tabcontrol: Sliding effect on tab item selection

Tags: wpf, animation, tabcontrol

I am having two tab items in my tab control and i want to give sliding effects (Animation) while selecting one tab item form another.
Let me know if anyone has some idea's to achieve this animation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/ed8801d8-51c4-4671-8b8c-86544c6d434d
this is helpful and evergreen..i have used it a while ago

This seems to be updated version
http://blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/01/26/TabControlStyling_PartTwo.aspx

and more over not sure what you meant by sliding effects?! any examples for me to understand

Comment: Actually, i am trying to give sliding effect to the contents of tab item. Let say, tabitem one contains one stackpanel and tabitem 2 contains some other controls then if i selected tab 2 then contents of tab 2 should get displayed in sliding manner.

Answer (score 1):

xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlAnimation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="maingrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TabTemplate">
                <Grid Name="gd">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TabControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabTemplate}" Name="_menuTabControl" TabStripPlacement="Top" Width="auto" Height="{Binding ElementName=maingrid, Path=Height}" SelectionChanged="_menuTabControl_SelectionChanged">
                <TabItem Header="MyTabItem1">
                    <Grid Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock Text="This is tab1"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>                      
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="MyTabItem2">
                    <Grid Background="Green">
                        <TextBlock Text="This is tab2"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>                      
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="MyTabItem3">
                    <Grid Background="Yellow">
                        <TextBlock Text="This is tab3"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>                      
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="MyTabItem4">
                    <Grid Background="Violet">
                        <TextBlock Text="This is tab4"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>                       
                </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="MyTabItem5">
                <Grid Background="Blue">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is tab5"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T:DependencyObject
    {
       if(depObj!=null)
       {
           for(int i=0;i<VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj);i++)
           {
               DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
               if (child != null && child is T)
                   yield return (T)child;

               foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                   yield return childOfChild;
           }
       }
    }


   int prev = -1, curr = -1;
    private void _menuTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        curr = (sender as TabControl).SelectedIndex;
        if(prev!=curr)
        {
            foreach(var rectangle in FindVisualChildren<Grid>(this))
            {
                if(rectangle.Name=="gd")
                {
                    DoubleAnimation translate_x=null;
                    if(prev>curr)
                    {
                        translate_x = new DoubleAnimation()
                        {
                            From = -300,
                            To = 0,
                            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3),

                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        translate_x = new DoubleAnimation()
                        {
                            From = 300,
                            To = 0,
                            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3),
                        };
                    }
                    var translate_y = new DoubleAnimation()
                    {
                        From = 0,
                        To = 0,
                        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    };
                    TranslateTransform translateTransform1 = new TranslateTransform();
                    translateTransform1.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, translate_x);
                    translateTransform1.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, translate_y);
                    rectangle.RenderTransform = translateTransform1;
                    prev = curr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```